# Laravel 8: delete() does not delete from the DB

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I'm working with Laravel 8 to develop my forum and I wanted to add some Like and Unlike functionality to question that have been asked by users.

So Like function works fine but for Unlike, I got some problem.

Here is the method for Unliking:

```
public function destroy(Question $id, Request $request)
    {
        $request->user()->likes()->where('question_id', $id)->delete();

        return back();
    }
```

And here is the form behind this:

```
<form action="{{ route('destroy.likes', $show->id) }}" method="POST">
   @csrf
   @method('DELETE')
   <button class="btn">
      <i class="fas fa-thumbs-down"></i>
   </button>
</form>
```

So the problem is it does not delete the data from table `likes` at the DB.

I tried `dd($request->user());` and `dd($id);`, they both *exists* with correct data, but I don't know why `delete()` does not work properly.

So if you know how to solve this, please let me know, I would really appreciate any idea or suggestion from you guys...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are passing a Question *object* in your `destroy` method, and then passing the whole object in your `where` call.

Try changing your `where` call to `where('question_id', $id->id)`, keeping in mind that your variable name is also called `id`. It may pay to clarify your variable name to `$question`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with your query, when you get the records that you want to delete:

app/Http/routes.php

```
Route::get('delete-records','YourController@index');
Route::get('delete/{id}','YourController@destroy')->name('destroy.likes');
```

Your View:

```
<a href="{{ route('destroy.likes', ['id' => $show->id]) }}" title="@lang('')">
   Delete
</a>
```

Controller Destroy Method:

```
public function destroy($id){
  $question = Question::find($id);
  $question ->delete();
  return back;
}
```